# SharePoint 2013 multiLingual site On-Prem Breadcrumbs are not converting into other languages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have SharePoint 2013 Internet site, we have implemented language variations for multilingual sites. Bread crumb is working fine if PC language is selected as English and in SharePoint I am selecting German.
But if my PC language is selected as German and in SharePoint also if language is selected as German then Breadcrumb is not showing in German Language.
Bread Crumbs are set up from Taxonomy. Please let me know if someone has faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this a couple of times, with different reasons for it, but fundamentally the same underlying reason. Very often breadcrumbs in lists that have managed navigation with or without friendly URLs come from a customization that is not out-of-the-box, and has been added to the Master Page. What they have in common is that they read a NavigationTerm.Title value. Unlike the term set on which it is based, this object does not support MUI, the Title does not return different value for different user languages.  That means that even if the Term Set on which it is based has labels for different languages set within the Managed Metadata Service, these are not available within the navigation, which just has the base language.

You can rewrite the code to open a TaxonomySession to retrieve the Name of the term in the current language, or you can use a third party multilingual SharePoint product but that may be overkill just for the breadcrumbs.